# Conditional replacement of new line character with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a corrupted text file in which I need to replace `\x20*[\n\r]+` with `\xa0` if next line (if exists) does no start with specific pattern `DATA\t`. If such line starts with spaces `\x20+`, those should be also removed.

Can I do it with `sed`? Text file is about 1MB of size.

---

*Data Example:*

```
DATA     132942, "I love you", 2398, "Hi how are you"
DATA     78793, "It is 
me", 4322, "My name is Frank"
DATA     24121, "Where
   are
you", 52432, "I am

here"
DATA     43242, "End of story", 432432, "The end"
```

*=>*

```
DATA     132942, "I love you", 2398, "Hi how are you"
DATA     78793, "It is me", 4322, "My name is Frank"
DATA     24121, "Where are you", 52432, "I am here"
DATA     43242, "End of story", 432432, "The end"
```

Comment: Can you show an example text and intended output?

Comment: @konsolebox - Added/updated...

Comment: I hope you could an example output as well. And are you sure it's `\xa0` not `\x0a`?

Comment: @konsolebox - Yes, I want `\xa0` space character, so I can later trace these replacements.

Comment: I followed your needed output. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749868/445221). Seems like you no longer need conversion to those markers first?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it in Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'puts File.read(ARGV.shift).gsub(/ *\r?\n *(?!DATA[[:space:]])/, " ").gsub(/ +$/m, "")' file
```

Output:

```
DATA    132942, "I love you", 2398, "Hi how are you"
DATA    78793, "It is me", 4322, "My name is Frank"
DATA    24121, "Where are you", 52432, "I am here"
DATA    43242, "End of story", 432432, "The end"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat input.txt | sed '{:q;N;s/\x20*[\n\r]\+/\xa0/g;t q}' | sed 's/\xa0DATA/\nDATA/g'
```

Comment: Shouldn't be second `sed` something like this? >> `sed 's[\x20\xa0]\+DATA\t/\nDATA\t/g'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nDATA/!s/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta;P;D' file
```